# How can i remove a line that Starts with "An" using bash commands?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm trying to copy a file but skip a specific line in the file that starts with 'An', using the bash in mac terminal.

The file only has 4 lines:

```
Kalle Andersson    036-134571
Bengt Pettersson   031-111111
Anders Johansson   08-806712
Per Eriksson       0140-12321
```

I know how to copy the file using the command `cp` and to grab a specific line in the file using the `grep` command. 
I do not know how i can delete a specific line i the file.

I have used the cp command:

```
cp file1.txt file2.txt
```

to copy the file.

And I used the

```
grep 'An' file2.txt
```

I expect the result where the new file have the three lines:

```
Kalle Andersson   036-134571
Bengt Pettersson  031-111111
Per Eriksson      0140-12321.
```

Is there an way I can do this in a single command?

Comment: `sed '/^An/d' file1.txt > file2.txt` or `grep -vE '^An' file1.txt > file2.txt`

Comment: you can just use `vim` to it as well `:g/^An/d`

Comment: for 4 lines, you can use the shell : while read line;do test -n "${line%%An*}" && echo "$line" ; done < infile > outfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Aaron said:

```
 grep -vE '^An' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

What you do here is use `grep` with the `-v` option. That means print every line, except the one that matches. Furthermore, you instruct the shell to redirect the output of the `grep` to `file2.txt`. That is the meaning of the`>`.

There are a lot of commands in Unix/Linux that can be used for this. `sed` is an obvious candidate, `awk` can do it, as in

```
awk '{if (!/^An/) print}' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Another option is `ed`:

```
ed file1.txt <<EOF
1
/^An
d
w file2.txt
q
EOF
```

Comment: er, .. yes, sorry. Editted it so it is correct.